# Выбрать данные за прошедший день

Tags: sql, mysql

В условии стоит такая конструкция:

```
TimeView > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

В базе две записи с **TimeView** одинаковым: `2014-05-06 22:38:18`
Запрос выполняется - почему?

Comment: Формат для NOW() соответствует формату даты в БД, значит дело в INTERVAL

Comment: вы же указали в условии: выбрать все записи с временем, которое больше чем день назад. вот и выполняется

Comment: Наверное, так будет правильно:
(video_view.TimeView > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND video_view.TimeView < FORMAT(NOW(), "YYYY-MM-DD"))

Comment: Тьфу блин...условие - смотрю на > а в голове <

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев:*

Вы указали в условии: выбрать все записи с временем, которое больше чем день назад.

```
video_view.TimeView > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
video_view.TimeView < CURDATE()
```